# ESP32 WROOM switching back from MicroPython to Arduino framework

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, firmware, esp32, python

I have recently switched my ESP32's firmware to work with Python (using Thonny IDE) and I want to switch back to work with C++ and the Arduino IDE, but I remember flashing that bin file on the device.

Is there any way of making it work with the Arduino IDE and C++ code?

Comment: upload the sketch from IDE. that is all

Answer (score 1):

Juraj's comment worked.
"upload the sketch from IDE. that is all – Juraj "